# How to create keymap (shortcut) for opening/navigating certain file in PhpStorm/IntelliJ?

Tags: intellij-idea, phpstorm, keymapping

Is there any way how to open/navigate certain file in current project just by hitting one key? How to map the shortcut to do this?

For example I have three files "file-one.php", "file-two.php" and "file-three.php" and when I press <kbd>F12</kbd>, editor would open file "file-three.php" and focus main editor window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this -- using **Bookmarks with mnemonics**.

You can bookmark actual file instead of particular line (yes, you can do it -- just do it while focus is in Project View panel) -- you will see assigned mnemonic symbol next to the file name.

In general:

- Shortcuts are rather predefined and limited to 10 only ("Bookmark 0" ... "Bookmark 9").
- By default it will be <kbd>Ctrl + 1</kbd> on Windows (depends on keymap used) .. but you may replace them by another one (look for `Other | Bookmarks | Go to Bookmark 0` and so on in `Settings/Preferences | Keymap`).
- Obviously ... bookmarks are project specific while shortcuts are IDE-wide setting.

Useful links:

- [Creating bookmarks with mnemonics](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/managing-bookmarks.html?search=book#createNumbered)
- [Navigating across the project](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/navigating-with-bookmarks.html?search=book#d191800e81)
- [Keymap](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/keymap.html)

---

NOTE: if you delete such bookmarked file (e.g. a log file that gets deleted on daily basis etc) .. then such association/bookmark will be lost once IDE will not be able to locate that file/target.

So either always keep that file present (make empty instead of deleting it) .. or re-bookmark it again.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should try `Recent Files` function! Press `⌘E` or `^E` and you will get a list of recent files, then just type file name and it will filter redundant files.

Document:

- https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/navigating-to-recent-file.html